# when do we get 400 bad request in spring when I populate the attribute with @Request body with JSON data which is there in the request body

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.0 for my application for back end services where I have a method to consumes json and produces json the method argument accepts DTO which is populated by the request body which has json for that I am using @request body.

Here my doubt is first I got 400 bad request error. Because in json there are no exact match of key:value with DTO fields. so Kept them.

But I don't what happen even I removed that parameters from JSON it is working fine. Spring is making the field values null which are not there in the JSON.

I just add transactional support to my spring. Is it b'coz of that?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve that putting these annotations in your DTO:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```